# BFGS method using constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-optimization

I am dealing with optimization of function of $6$ variables, where I have $4$ constrains. Is [Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) (BFGS) suitable for optimization with constraints?

Comment: yes, IPOPT and SNOPT are examples of algorithms that have implemented this

Comment: @LinAlg thank you